# Marker in leaflet JS does not load properly due to ERR_INVALID_URL error

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, leaflet

I am trying to add markers to my Leaflet map but they don't show up.

In the console I see an network error: net::ERR_INVALID_URL for a http request loading an image like this:

```
Request URL: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA.....SUVORK5CYII=")marker-icon-2x.png
```

If I remove that last part of the URL

```
)marker-icon-2x.png
```

I end up with a proper base64 encoded image. So I guess the question is what that marker-icon is added in the end of the URL.

More background:

- My code looks something like this:

```
L.marker(coords).bindPopup(someName).addTo(this.map)
```

- My map renders correctly and I can draw polygons on it and more.
- I'm using Vue and Vue2Leaflet
- I have imported the leaflet.css
- I have tried to include these lines of code without effect:

```
delete Icon.Default.prototype._getIconUrl

Icon.Default.mergeOptions({
  iconRetinaUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon-2x.png'),
  iconUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png'),
  shadowUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png')
});
```

Comment: if you solved this your solution would be much appreciated!

Comment: For the root cause and several possible solutions, see https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4968#issuecomment-483402699

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```js
import L from 'leaflet';
delete L.Icon.Default.prototype._getIconUrl;

L.Icon.Default.mergeOptions({
    iconRetinaUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon-2x.png').default,
    iconUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png').default,
    shadowUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png').default,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Providing some default values to 'icon' property of l-marker as below solved this issue for me. Still, it needs a default valid image path always which means that we must have at least one image or its valid URL available.
BTW, that L object mentioned below is imported from 'leaflet' package.

```
defaultIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: require('../assets/logo.png'),
        shadowUrl: require('../assets/logo.png'),
    });
```